# Intercept another web application requests

Tags: web, servlets, jakarta-ee, websphere, servlet-filters

I have 2 ear application (Primary and Proxy).
The primary application is build using Servlet JSP MVC.

Now, I want to create a Proxy application (ear app) to listen and log all the  requests and response going and coming from the Primary application.

I cannot modify the Primary application, have only control on the Proxy application that I am writing.

Can I write a simple Servlet Filter to listen all the requests on my primary application.

Note: Both the applications will run in WAS, may be same ports can be configured.

I WILL RECEIVE THE REQUESTS ONLY on my PRIMARY APPLICATION. Hence I feel using RequestDispatcher may not be the appropriate one. Kindly advice.

Comment: So you want the server, port, and context-root (e.g. `/primary`) to stay the same, but some other application to intercept those requests and pass them on? I don't think you're going to be able to do that with just another ear. WebSphere won't let two different applications bind to the same host/port/context-root

Comment: Context root would be different, 
Primary (/primary)
Proxy (/proxy)
Not sure about the ports, It can be different.

Comment: I tried in local running these 2 different application on same port. They are rendering the result. Now, I want my Proxy application to listen on all requests that are coming to my Primary Application